# horizontal scroll not work in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My horizontal scroll is not working in ie 7. 
my code is here below

```
.twitter_inner
{
    position: relative;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:135%;
}
```

Comment: Please provide full details about your problem. This is insufficient.

Answer (score 6):

The overflow-x and overflow-y styles in IE7 are only partially supported. If you specify a hidden value on either a overflow-x or a overflow-y style then IE7 will automatically default the other's visible or scroll  to hidden as well, so that's your problem.

The solution would be to set your overflow-x style to auto:

```
.twitter_inner
{
        position: relative;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    width:135%;
}
```

That way the hidden value on your overflow-y style will not over ride the value on your overflow-x style.